# How to create Status Chart

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I try to use Range Bar chart to create Status Chart like this [image]

However,There is error while I execute
[image]
Here is the code I collected from [How can I make a gannt chart with overlapping points in winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57623080/how-can-i-make-a-gannt-chart-with-overlapping-points-in-winforms)

```
 public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Chart chart2 = new Chart();
        setUpGantt(chart2);
        Series s = chart2.Series[0];
        addGanttTask(s, "8:00", "17:00", Color.LimeGreen, 1);
        addGanttTask(s, "9:00", "9:20", Color.DarkSlateBlue, 1);
        addGanttTask(s, "11:00", "12:00", Color.DarkSlateBlue, 1);
        addGanttTask(s, "13:00", "13:20", Color.DarkSlateBlue, 1);
        s.SetCustomProperty("PixelPointWidth", "15");
    }
    void setUpGantt(Chart chart)
    {
       ...
    }

    void limitGantt(Chart chart, string start, string end)
    {
       ...
    }
    DateTime fromTimeString(string time)
    {
       ....
    }
    void addGanttTask(Series s, string start, string end, Color c, int slot)
    {
       ....
    }
```

Please help me how to correct it !Thank you

Comment: From what I can see. `chart2` is never assigned a `ChartArea`. Try adding: `chart2.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());` after the chart has been created. I can only assume that setting up the chart area is missing from the link you posted.

Comment: @JohnG After I added it . There is no error However It doesn't exit chart on the form

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by: _”It doesn’t exit chart on the form”_ ? From what I can see from the posted link and @TaW s answer, it appears his code is adding the chart to the form from the designer and this code is not shown. In your case, you are adding a “new” chart with the code… `Chart chart2 = new Chart();` … however it does not appear that you are adding the “new” chart to the form. Try adding this line to the end `this.Controls.Add(chart2);`.

Comment: Sorry for my typo "It doesn’t exist chart on the form"

Comment: Are you able to see the chart after adding it to the form? If not… Add the line `this.Controls.Add(chart2);` right after the line … `s.SetCustomProperty("PixelPointWidth", "15");`

Comment: Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'

Comment: Wait! … it looks like you are using the incorrect “Using” statement. It appears you are using ` `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting` … change it to `using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;`

Comment: Great. It worked. Thank you so much

Comment: I am not that familiar with “charting” and initially, the chart bar depth was smaller than shown in the picture. I am assuming the line: `s.SetCustomProperty("PixelPointWidth", "15");` is controlling this. To make the bar height larger change the “15” to something like “75”. Glad you got it working.