# How to create status chart by MS chart

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I just created this chart by Range Bar chart
[image]

```
 public Form1()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
        setUpGantt(chart2);
        Series s1 = chart2.Series[0];
        addGanttTask(s1, "0:00", "23:00", Color.LimeGreen, 1);
        addGanttTask(s1, "9:00", "9:20", Color.Red, 1);
        addGanttTask(s1, "11:00", "12:00", Color.DarkSlateBlue, 1);
        addGanttTask(s1, "13:00", "13:20", Color.Aqua, 1);
        s1.Points[0].AxisLabel = "Machine 2";

        chart2.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
        chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 1;

        chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MinorGrid.Enabled = false;
        chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = true;
        chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MinorGrid.Enabled = true;
        chart2.Legends[0].Enabled = false;
      
    }
```

I learnt from [How can I make a gannt chart with overlapping points in winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57623080/how-can-i-make-a-gannt-chart-with-overlapping-points-in-winforms)

I expect to create horizontal stacked bar chart like this.
[image]
Please help me how to do it. Thank you

Comment: You need to make a `ChartArea` for each range bar chart, but add all the chart areas to the same `Chart` object.

Comment: __No__! She simply needs to add another Series for each of those bars/machines.Additional ChartAreas would only complicate matters..