# How to display multiple legend for range bar chart

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I study from [How can I make a gannt chart with overlapping points in winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57623080/how-can-i-make-a-gannt-chart-with-overlapping-points-in-winforms)
So I try to show all legend for that chart But it showed only one ledgend
Please help how to do it

```
 public Form1()
   {
    InitializeComponent();
    Chart chart2 = new Chart();
    chart2.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea());
    chart2.Dock= DockStyle.Top;
    this.Controls.Add(chart2);
    setUpGantt(chart2);
    Series s = chart2.Series[0];
    addGanttTask(s, "8:00", "17:00", Color.LimeGreen, 1);
    addGanttTask(s, "9:00", "9:20", Color.DarkSlateBlue, 1);
    addGanttTask(s, "11:00", "12:00", Color.DarkSlateBlue, 1);
    addGanttTask(s, "13:00", "13:20", Color.DarkSlateBlue, 1);
    s.SetCustomProperty("PixelPointWidth", "15");
    s.Points[0].AxisLabel = "Machine 1";
}
void setUpGantt(Chart chart)
{
   ...
}

void limitGantt(Chart chart, string start, string end)
{
   ...
}
DateTime fromTimeString(string time)
{
   ....
}
void addGanttTask(Series s, string start, string end, Color c, int slot)
{
   ....
}
```

[image]

Comment: What should be the label of those legends you want to add? Because if i'm not mistaken 1 Legend is equivalent to 1 Series.

Comment: @tontonsevilla   I expect every label of those legends

Answer (score 0):

If this is the output you want:
[image]

Step 1: Create a Series for every gantt task you are adding.
Step 2: Make sure that you are always using First Series

```
int pt = chart.Series[0].Points.AddXY(slot, start_ , end_);
chart.Series[0].Points[pt].Color = c;
```