# Is there any way to make a Timeline chart in windows forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I am trying to make a timeline. I found this [How can I make a gannt chart with overlapping points in winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57623080/how-can-i-make-a-gannt-chart-with-overlapping-points-in-winforms#) , and I am using it by now like this:

```
void limitGantt(Chart chart, DateTime start, DateTime end)
        {
            Axis ax = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
            ax.Minimum = 0.5; 
            ax.Maximum = 1.5;  

            Axis ay = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
            ay.Minimum = start.ToOADate();
            ay.Maximum = end.ToOADate();
        }

void addGanttTask(Series s, DateTime start, DateTime end, Color c, int slot, string label)
        {

            int pt = s.Points.AddXY(slot, start, end);
            s.Points[pt].Color = c;
            s.Points[pt].Label = label;
            s.Points[pt].LabelAngle = -90;
            s.Points[pt].LabelBackColor = Color.White;
            
        }

void setUpGantt(Chart chart, DateTime start, DateTime end)
        {
            chart.Series.Clear();
            Series s = chart.Series.Add("gantt");
            s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.RangeBar;
            s.YValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
            s.XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
            s.AxisLabel = "";
            s.IsVisibleInLegend = false;
            Axis ax = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
            Axis ay = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
            ax.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
            ax.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
            ax.LabelStyle.Format = " ";
            ax.Enabled = AxisEnabled.False;
            ay.LabelStyle.Format = "HH:mm";
            ay.LabelAutoFitStyle = LabelAutoFitStyles.DecreaseFont;
            ay.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
            ay.MajorTickMark.Enabled = false;
            ay.LabelStyle.Angle = 90;
            ay.LineColor = chart.BackColor;
            ay.LabelAutoFitMaxFontSize = 6;
            limitGantt(chart, start, end);
        }

setUpGantt(frm1.chartTimeLine, start, end);
Series s = frm1.chartTimeLine.Series[0];

addGanttTask(s, firstEvent, firstEvent, Color.DarkSlateBlue, 1, "First Event");
addGanttTask(s, secondEvent, secondEvent, Color.DarkSlateBlue, 1, "Second Event");
```

As you can see, I have set the start & end value as the same.
This is the result:
[timeline attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1StY.png)

Is not so nice... also the labels positions are not accurate (i.e. 1st event time is represented  (more or less)after 11:00 when the true value is 10:55, and also if they are so close they overlap.

Does anyone know another way to make a TimeLine, or at least what I am doing wrong with the labels?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Is it a requirement to create a hand-rolled approach? If not there are numerous Gantt chart controls out there such as: https://www.devcomponents.com/kb2/?p=404 & https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/chart-working-with-gantt-chart-data

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately I have to do it without any "commercial" component / control...

Comment: No worries, have you had a look around for pre-built controls on Nuget/Github like the following with MIT licenses? https://github.com/jakesee/ganttchart. As always, someone else will have had a similar situation and majority of the time are open to sharing the controls they have created